# Java Comparator class to sort particular object array

Tags: java, android

I have a float array and  a String array. 
each float value match with a specific String. 
I would like to sort the float array keeping the own string using :

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a,Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Here is the code:

```
public class ResultVoiceObject
{

     private  String frase;
     private float ranking;
     public ResultVoiceObject(String f, float r) 
       {
        this.frase=f;
        this.ranking= r;
       }  
     }
     public class VoiceRecognitionDemo extends Activity
     {

       // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);          
        //il Ranking
        float[] score= data.getFloatArrayExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES);

        ResultVoiceObject[] risultati= new ResultVoiceObject[score.length];
        for (i=0; i<risultati.length;i++)
        {       
            risultati[i]=new ResultVoiceObject(matches.get(i), score[i]);       
        }          
        ResultVoiceObject[] risultatiDaOrdinare= risultati;  // risultati contais ResultVoiceObject elements
                    /*sorting*/
        }
```

How can I sort by ranking and keeping the own String?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please show us the code you tried to solve this problem with

Comment: I don't have code, I don't know how to use Arrays.sort with object like mine.
I solved in another way but my manager would likes I use Array.sort(result, Comparator). Can I?

Comment: yes you can and google will help

Comment: you need to create your own comparator, for example ResultVoiceObjectComparator

Comment: Shouldn't that be phrase? : S

Comment: I have tried giving full explanation . Please see my updated answer. I would really appreciate the attention given to it

Comment: Will this compare in ascending order or descending?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ResultVoiceObject[] objects = ...
Arrays.sort(objects, new Comparator<ResultVoiceObject>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(ResultVoiceObject arg0, ResultVoiceObject arg1) {
        return Float.compare(arg0.getRanking(), arg1.getRanking());
    }

});
```

Comment: error:
Multiple markers at this line
 - Comparator cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments 
  (ResultVoiceObject[], new Comparator<ResultVoiceObject>(){})

Comment: `import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;`

Comment: yes it's true! So I deleted the implements and compare methos! I voted you thanks!

Comment: I posted a complete solution!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a `getRanking()` accessor for the private field `ranking`.

```
public class ResultComparator implements Comparator<ResultVoiceObject> {
  public int compare(ResultVoiceObject r1, ResultVoiceObject r2) {
    float f1 = r1.getRanking();
    float f2 = r2.getRanking();
    if(f1 > f2) return 1;
    else if(f1 < f2) return -1;
    return 0;
  }

}

Arrays.sort(resultsArray, new ResultComparator());
```

Comment: Watch out! Implementing comparator by using arithmetic operations can result in wrong sort order because of overflow.

Comment: `(int)r1.getRanking() - (int)r2.getRanking();` meaning that i.e. `7.1 == 7.2`?

Comment: @gma, I was in the process of editing my post. Sorry for that.

Comment: thanks i solved with another solution, you can see on my post

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the `Comparator` interface. You can create multiple sort sequences while using `Comparator`.

Suppose you want to sort your array according to your ranking, then create a separate class which implements `Comparator`

```
public Class RankingSorter implements Comparator<ResultVoiceObject> {
   public int compare(ResultVoiceObject one, ResultVoiceObject another){
       return (int)(one.getRanking() - another.getRanking());
   }
}
```

Then in the new class that you want to sort your array, 
You create the object of the `comparator` and pass it to collection

```
RankingSorter rs = new RankingSorter();
Collections.sort(yourArray, rs);
```

This is the overloaded version of `sort` method which takes the `comparator`.

I had written a full tutorial regarding this a while ago
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/174322-the-comparable-and-comparator-interface-part-ii/

Here is the ResultVoicObject class

```
package com.compare;

public class ResultVoiceObject {

private String frase;
private float ranking;

public ResultVoiceObject(String f, float r) {
    this.frase = f;
    this.ranking = r;
}

public String getFrase() {
    return frase;
}

public void setFrase(String frase) {
    this.frase = frase;
}

public float getRanking() {
    return ranking;
}

public void setRanking(float ranking) {
    this.ranking = ranking;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ResultVoiceObject [frase=" + frase + ", ranking=" + ranking
            + "]";
}

}
```

Implement the `Comparator` interface as follows, you need to implement `compare` method

```
 package com.compare;

 import java.util.Comparator;

  public class RankingSort implements Comparator<ResultVoiceObject> {

public int compare(ResultVoiceObject one, ResultVoiceObject another){
    return (int) (one.getRanking() - another.getRanking());
}
  }
```

You can test it as below.

```
 package com.compare;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;

 public class RankingSorterTest{

public static void main(String [] args){

    ArrayList<ResultVoiceObject> list = new ArrayList<ResultVoiceObject>();
    list.add(new ResultVoiceObject("one", 1));
    list.add(new ResultVoiceObject("five", 5));
    list.add(new ResultVoiceObject("three", 3));

    Collections.sort(list,new RankingSort());
    System.out.println(list);

}
  }
```

If you want to create a sorting sequence using frase, then you just need to create a new `comparator` class for it and sort just as I have sorted above

Hope this helps... took a lot of efforts from me also :D :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved merging both answare:

```
public class VoiceRecognitionDemo extends Activity implements Comparator<ResultVoiceObject {

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
        ...
        ResultVoiceObject[] risultati= ...;     
        Arrays.sort(risultati, new Comparator<ResultVoiceObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ResultVoiceObject arg0, ResultVoiceObject arg1) {
                return Float.compare(arg0.getRanking(), arg1.getRanking());
            }
        });  

    }


public int compare(ResultVoiceObject lhs, ResultVoiceObject rhs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Where:

```
 public class ResultVoiceObject
 {

 private  String frase;
 private float ranking;
 public ResultVoiceObject(String f, float r) 
   {
    this.frase=f;
    this.ranking= r;
   }  
 }
```

Another way is:

ADD

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Comparator;

REMOVE: implements Comparator and the compare methos out onActivityResult

Thanks stackoverflow comunity!