# How do I sort a List in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, I have a List, and I want to sort it. Is there a method in the that will do this for me?

The list to sort `List<Caution>`

I want to sort it using `lbEtatCaution`

The entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TG_CAUTION")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Caution implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Transient
public static String NOM_DOSSIER_CAUTION_DEFAULT =" ";

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="TG_CAUTION_IDCAUTION_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SID_CAUTION" , allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TG_CAUTION_IDCAUTION_GENERATOR")
@Column(name="ID_CAUTION")
private long idCaution;

@Column(name="DT_CAUTION")
private Timestamp dtCaution;

@Column(name="DT_ETAT")
private Timestamp dtEtat;

@Column(name="DT_RECEPTION")
private Timestamp dtReception;

@Column(name="MT_CAUTION" ,columnDefinition="number")
private double mtCaution;

@Column(name="RF_DOSSIER")
private String rfDossier;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TcEtatCaution
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CD_ETAT_CAUTION")
private EtatCaution tcEtatCaution;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgAgentCaution
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_AGENT")
private AgentCaution tgAgentCaution;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgCaution
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_CAUTION_REMPLACEE")
private Caution tgCaution;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgCaution
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tgCaution")
private List<Caution> tgCautions;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgCompteCaution
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_COMPTE_CAUTION")
private CompteCaution tgCompteCaution;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgHistoCaution
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tgCaution")
private List<HistoCaution> tgHistoCautions;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgRejet
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tgCaution")
private List<Rejet> tgRejets;


//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgApprehension
//@OneToMany(mappedBy="tgCaution")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_CAUTION")
private List<Apprehension> tgApprehensions;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgBordereau
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tgCaution")
private List<Bordereau> tgBordereaus;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgTransfertSirepa
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tgCaution")
private List<TransfertSirepa> tgTransfertSirepas;

public Caution() {
}
//getters and setters
}
```

Entity EtatCaution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TC_ETAT_CAUTION")
public class EtatCaution implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="CD_ETAT_CAUTION")
private long cdEtatCaution;

@Column(name="LB_ETAT_CAUTION")
private String lbEtatCaution;

@Column(name="MN_ETAT_CAUTION" , columnDefinition="char")
private String mnEtatCaution;

public EtatCaution() {
}
//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: have you read up on comparators and Collections.sort()?

Comment: no, I founded an example, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your entity class implement `Comparable<EtatCaution>`.

```
public int compareTo(EtatCaution compareObject)
{
    return lbEtatCaution.compareTo(compareObject.lbEtatCaution);
}
```

Then, just call `Collections.sort(myList)`.

Comment: I want to sort it by `lbEtatCaution` attibute

Comment: Yes, that is what you put in the compareTo method that the `Comparable<EtatCaution>` interface defines.

Comment: Just edited my reply to give an example implementation.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus, when using comparable, he will have to modify the same class. Using comparator, he can create a different comparator altogether and pass it to `Collections.sort()`

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I don't necessarily think that's bad, as long as it is code you have under your control. A matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: Dude, I never said its bad :) Just that he can create multiple comparator using Comparator

Comment: The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String

Comment: Ah, thats a string. My mistake. Correction is above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@OrderBy` on the relevant relation, e.g.

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to TgCaution
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tgCaution")
@OrderBy("lbEtatCaution ASC")
private List<Caution> tgCautions;
```

For more information, please see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html

Comment: +1, only post that talks about sorting at query level, and infact it is the best approach. (why should i first get the list and than sort it, rather i should get the sorted list itself).

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem using Jan Doerrenhaus solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `comparator` interface. There is a similar question which I had answered. This will help you 
This post would help you [Java Comparator class to sort particular object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164117/java-comparator-class-to-sort-particular-object-array/17164349#17164349)

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem using Jan Doerrenhaus solution!

Answer (score 0):

implement your entity class from `Comparable` interface and
use

```
Collection.sort(yourList);
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem using Jan Doerrenhaus solution!