# sort values in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have values in linked list as

> TY12354d,sfasdf,asfasf,2.35123412E8
>
> TY12354dsaf,asdffasd,asfasfafsd,12344.0
>
> Pranish,pranishfilan,viper,1234
>
> zxs,asdf,asfd,1234
>
> uv,vr,va,1234
>
> www,dsf,ASDF,123
>
> dsfgsdf,sd,sd,235

The values are seperated by commas which contains certain data. The first ones i.e TY12354d, TY12345saf, Pranish etc are the id, second i.e sfasdf, asdffasd, pranishfilan, etc are name.The values are viewed in jtextfield.  I want to enable user to sort the datas according to the id when he clicks on "sort by id" button, name when he clicks on "sort by name" button and so on.

Comment: If you have structure like `id`, `name` and so on it would be easier to create class with same structure (field for `id`, `name` and so on), place instances of such class in your list and sort it with custom comparator.

Comment: yes I have definitely done that way I added teh objects of class Car in the linked list as
linkedList.addLast(new Car(id,name...))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one to sort by id.

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

list.add("TY12354d,sfasdf,asfasf,2.35123412E8");
list.add("TY12354dsaf,asdffasd,asfasfafsd,12344.0");
list.add("Pranish,pranishfilan,viper,1234");
list.add("zxs,asdf,asfd,1234");
list.add("uv,vr,va,1234");
list.add("www,dsf,ASDF,123");
list.add("dsfgsdf,sd,sd,235");

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println(a+" --> "+b);
        return a.substring(0, a.indexOf(',')).compareTo(b.substring(0, b.indexOf(',')));
    }
});
```

Use same concept for name also.

output:

```
Pranish,pranishfilan,viper,1234
TY12354d,sfasdf,asfasf,2.35123412E8
TY12354dsaf,asdffasd,asfasfafsd,12344.0
dsfgsdf,sd,sd,235
uv,vr,va,1234
www,dsf,ASDF,123
zxs,asdf,asfd,1234
```

---

--EDIT--

as per OP last comment to compare on `Car` object

```
class Car {
    String id;
    String name;

    public Car(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // getter & setter
}

LinkedList<Car> list = new LinkedList<Car>();

list.add(new Car("TY12354d", "sfasdf"));
list.add(new Car("TY12354dsaf", "asdffasd"));
list.add(new Car("Pranish", "pranishfilan"));
list.add(new Car("zxs", "asdf"));
list.add(new Car("uv", "vr"));
list.add(new Car("www", "dsf"));
list.add(new Car("dsfgsdf", "sd"));

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Car>() {
    public int compare(Car c1, Car c2) {
        return c1.id.compareTo(c2.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the value of a here? And is b the new Comparator?

Comment: `Comparator` automatically takes two values from list and compare one by one till the end of list. Just try to print the value.

Comment: sorry sir but could you please give me a code example

Comment: @viper you haven't tried what I said you. OK let me update my post then try it yourself to learn it yourself.

Comment: Now try it. I just added one `System.out.println(a+" --> "+b);`

Comment: what is the meaning if 'list' here? is it the linked list?? I kept linked list here but gives error as

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Car cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at CarTest$17.compare(CarTest.java:738)
 at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:351)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:216)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1435)

Comment: OK as per your question you are talking about to sort string list. Let me update my post.

Comment: ok and how to check the values whether they are sorted or not. And how to display them in a jtextarea as it is sorted

Comment: Why you want to check it? just sort it when needed.

Comment: Yes thank you. This method worked. But sometimes it doesn't sort properly I don't know why. And how to compare double values in this way, to sort linked list

Comment: use `Double#compareTo()` method.  for e.g. `Double.valueOf(1.2).compareTo(Double.valueOf(2.2))`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write your own comparator, or rewrite the structure. With a comparator you can simply use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) to sort the list.

There are many threads on implementing comparators here on stackoverflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164303/645270). It's actually fairly simple.

It's not very efficient to sort a linked list, so if you don't use `Collections.sort`, which uses an intermediate array to sort, I'd suggest that you change your datastructure to e.g. an array or ArrayList. Or, even better: create a Class to represent your data and define comparators for that class.

Here's an example of a Comparator:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {

    static class IDComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            return a.split(",")[0].compareToIgnoreCase(b.split(",")[0]);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
        ll.add("TY12354d,sfasdf,asfasf,2.35123412E8");
        ll.add("TY12354dsaf,asdffasd,asfasfafsd,12344.0");
        ll.add("Pranish,pranishfilan,viper,1234");

        System.out.println("Before sorting on ID:\n");
        for (String s : ll) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        Collections.sort(ll,new IDComparator());
        System.out.println("\nAfter sorting on ID:\n");
        for (String s : ll) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before sorting on ID:

TY12354d,sfasdf,asfasf,2.35123412E8
TY12354dsaf,asdffasd,asfasfafsd,12344.0
Pranish,pranishfilan,viper,1234

After sorting on ID:

Pranish,pranishfilan,viper,1234
TY12354d,sfasdf,asfasf,2.35123412E8
TY12354dsaf,asdffasd,asfasfafsd,12344.0
```

This is not the prettiest code I've written. I especially don't like the comparator itself, with a hard coded index. However, it'll give you an idea of how to proceed with custom comparators.